# Unable to kill remote commands by name through ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

I want to execute commands to get the processid by name and kill all the processes it has listed from another machine remotely, through ssh. I am running the below command,

```
ssh user@ip "kill -SIGINT `ps -ef | grep <process name> | awk '{print $2}'`"
```

But it is checking locally for the process name instead of checking on the remote machine.

Can you anyone help me on why this command is not working properly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it a lot more simply:

```
ssh user@ip "pkill -INT <process name>"
```

See also the `-f` option for `pkill`.

Answer (score 1):

Double quotes are interpreted by the shell, before the command is called. You have to put the parameter in single quotes:

```
ssh user@ip 'kill -SIGINT `ps -ef | grep <process name> | awk "{print \$2}"`'
```